# redirect() / render_template() enters the route once again when called from the same route in Flask

Tags: python, flask, redirect, post, back

I have created a wishlist page which lists the items wishlisted by a user. The user can remove any item from the wishlist by clicking on the Remove button. On clicking the remove button, the HTML `<form>` submits it to the back-end application. The back-end application then removes the item from the wishlist database and redirects back to the same page using `return redirect(url_for('wishlist'))`.

The problem I am facing is that if the user goes back after removing the item from the wishlist he has to go back twice to reach the page from where the user came from. This is caused due to the redirect that I am performing after removing the item which is necessary to show the updated wishlist.

I have also tried `render_template()` instead of `redirect()` but it is also causing the same problem.

Code for back-end:

```
@app.route('/wishlist/',methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def wishlist():

    userid=current_user.get_id()

    if request.method=='POST':
        toRemove=request.form['remove']
        deleteWish=session.query(Wishlist).filter_by(userId=userid,productId=toRemove).one()
        session.delete(deleteWish)
        session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('wishlist'))

    subquery=session.query(Wishlist.productId).filter(Wishlist.userId==userid).subquery()
    wishes=session.query(Products).filter(Products.id.in_(subquery))

    return render_template("wishlist.html",wishes=wishes)
```

HTML:

```
<html>

<body>

    {% for wish in wishes %}
        <img src={{wish.image_path}} width="150" height="200">
        </br>
        {{wish.material}}
        {{wish.productType}}
        </br>
        {{wish.price}}
        </br>
        <form action="{{url_for('wishlist')}}" method="POST" target="_self">
            <button name="remove" type="submit" value="{{wish.id}}">Remove</button>
        </form>
        </br>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

Please suggest me a way to prevent this.

Comment: You can have AJAX process your submission and reload the page afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to create a different end point for deleting wishes. This endpoint then redirects to your wish list once deletion is done.

> FLASK

```
@app.route('/wishlist/',methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
userid=current_user.get_id()
def wishlist():
 subquery=session.query(Wishlist.productId).filter(Wishlist.userId==userid).subquery()
    wishes=session.query(Products).filter(Products.id.in_(subquery))
    return render_template("wishlist.html")

@app.route('/deletewish', methods = ['GET', 'POST']
def deletewish():
if request.method=='POST':
    toRemove=request.form['wish_delete_id']    
    deleteWish=...
    session.delete(deleteWish)
    session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('wishlist'))
```

> HTML

```
<html>

<body>
{% for wish in wishes %}
        <img src={{wish.image_path}} width="150" height="200">
        </br>
        {{wish.material}}
        {{wish.productType}}
        </br>
        {{wish.price}}
        </br>
        <form method="POST" target="_self">
            <button class="remove_wish" type="submit" value={{wish.id}}>Remove</button>
        </form>
    </br>
{% endfor %}`
<script src='path_to_jquery.js'></script>
<script src='path_to_deletewish.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

> JS //deletewish.js content

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.remove_wish').click(function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
    data : {
            wish_delete_id : $(this).val();
            },
        type : 'POST',
        url : '/deletewish',
        success: function (data) {
            location.reload();
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert('something went wrong')
        }
    });
});
})
</script>
```

Comment: Tried this, but the problem still exists because here also you are redirecting after removing the item from the wishlist in `deletewish()`. Since the user will first enter the wishlist page and then if the user removes an item he gets redirected to wishlist page again, so he need to go back twice to reach the page from where he entered the wishlist.

Comment: In that case, I can guide you through using AJAX and jQuery if you wish

Comment: Yes please, that will be a great help!

Comment: Thanks for the update!! but I am facing a problem: When I click on the remove button I get the following error: **NoResultFound: No row was found for one()**. Also `toRemove=request.form['wish_delete_id']` is None everytime when I click on Remove button.

Comment: I've update my code to show an alert, whenever the delete button is clicked. Check if the content of the alert corresponds to the wish-id.

Comment: Its working fine now. The problem was that ajax was posting twice, so I added `event.preventDefault()` and it got fixed. Also I changed `return redirect(url_for('wishlist'))` to `return jsonify(status="success")` so that GET does not execute twice, is doing this fine?

Comment: That's fine. Congrats.

Comment: I just found one more problem: In the wishlist if I remove the topmost element it gets removed successfully but if I remove any following item after the first one, I get the same error  **NoResultFound: No row was found for one()** and alert also does not show up. Is this because of the form in a loop?

Comment: I have edited the code and now its working fine! The problem was due to the use of id instead of class in button.